# Memcache error on windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, command-prompt, windows-10-desktop

I use xampp and windows 10 **64bit** and my **php version is 7.1.4**, I downloaded **memcached-win64-1.4.4-14** and put it in C drive: C:\memcached.
When i run this command:

> c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d install

I receive this error:

> failed to install service or service already installed

and:

> c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d start

I receive this error:

> failed to start service

Please tell me where the problem is? thanks.

Comment: open `services.msc` using Run (Win+R), check if memcached is there or not. never tried to install it.. but check it first.. also, is there any verbose options on `memcached.exe -d start`?

Comment: Thank you **Bagus Tesa**, yes, this service exists but when i want to get started, this eruption arises: The system cannot find the filespecified.

Comment: thats the funny part, we need to check in registry for it.. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`.. whether it points to the correct file.. however, i am afraid we will need to salvage from memcache logs also.. perhaps it was looking something in the path that did no exits..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the issue was solved! i should **copy** **the memcahced folder** in the **xampp folder** and **then execute** the previous commands.
It's over, hope to be useful to others.
Thank you **Bagus Tesa**

Answer (score 2):

I my case, I should open the cmd "Run as administrator" in order to run those commands.